# Do Widgets in iOS 11 run in the foreground or background?

Tags: ios, notifications, widget, ios11, nsnotificationcenter

Do Widgets in iOS 11 run in the foreground or background?

Are Widgets updated/call the containing app when the Today View or Notification Center is simply interacted with on an iPhone? or must the Widget be physically touched/selected to update or communicate with the containing app?

Is the Notification Center or Today View considered an app? I know Today is an extension but what is NC classified as?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: no I did not, if you have any insight into this that would be awesome!

Comment: I don’t - sorry!